# success url in views.py

Tags: python, django, url

I was trying to add a success URL to my views.py But it didn't work


views.py:

```py
def register(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    password1 = request.POST.get('password1')
    password2 = request.POST.get('password2')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)        
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    
    context = {'forms':form}
    return render(request, 'register/register.html', context)
```

my urls.py:

```
 urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.register, name = 'register'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='register/login.html'), name = 'login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='entry/home'), name = 'logout'),
]
```

register.html:

```
{% extends '../base.html' %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    {% block content %}
    
    <title>Register</title>
    <style>
        .container{
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com" name="username">
            <label for="floatingInput">Username</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com" name="email">
            <label for="floatingInput">Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password" name="password1">
            <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password" name="password2">
            <label for="floatingPassword">Re-Type Password</label>
        </div>
        
     
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
{% endblock content %}
</html>
```

I want when he click submit to go to the 'home' URL,
when i click the button id do save the user in my Django database but it dont go to the login page it stay on the register template

Comment: First you need to define in urls and where in your code you see that you redirecting him

Comment: @NirElbaz how i will do that

Comment: Can you please show us the client side ?

Comment: In general you need to "Catch" the submit and when it happened to redirect it

Comment: what do u mean by the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use redirect:

```
return redirect('index')
```

Comment: i tried to use it but it did give me that it is not defined

Comment: replace `index` with your view name in `urls.py`

Answer (score 0):

When you press submit , the html page will send in the Post request the event ,
To make it easier change:

```
<button type="submit">Register</button>
```

to :

```
<button type="submit" name='Register'>Register</button>
```

In you python code add (after what you want it happen):

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.POST.get("Register"):
        return render(request,app/index.html'           )
```

In Url add:

```
url(r'^home$', app.views.home, name='home')
```

add in views.py:

```
def home(request):
    """Renders the home page."""   
    return render(
        request,
        'app/index.html'        
    )
```

Comment: Can you please put a breakdown at  if request.method == 'POST': and see if you see the button Register?